# Is memory freed when the length of an NSString is reduced or do I have to do something more?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory

If I have the following code:

```
NSString* test = @"12345... 1Kb worth of characters";
test = [test substringFromIndex:512];
```

Then would the memory consumed by test be halved (from 1024 to 512 bytes) or do I have to do something to tell it to release the memory?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After such call new memory for substring will be `allocated`. But your string `test` is marked as `autoreleased`. So previous value of `test` will be automatically `released` and new value will be assigned. Notice that new value (substring) will be too `autoreleased` and you don't need to `release` it manually.

Comment: It’s better to say that the string is not owned by that particular code. Technically, that string is **not** autoreleased.

Answer (score 2):

Since the memory which you refer to is allocated statically - in this case you are okay.

```
NSString* test = @"12345... 1Kb worth of characters";
test = [test substringFromIndex:512];
```

However, in the following case:

```
NSString *s = [@"some long string" retain];
s = [s substringFromIndex:someLongNumber];
```

You would have a memory leak, since the memory occupied by `s` at the point of the second assignment will have lost its reference, thereby rendering you unable to eventually release the memory that was previously occupied in the location referenced by `s`.

Comment: NSString* test = @"12345... 1Kb worth of characters"; //autoreleased. -> this is not correct. string literals are created on stack not on heap. To test it, create NSString * test; with class scope and in a method test = @"243432432432", in next method try NSLog(@"Test string %@",test); String literals are not autoreleased objects.

Comment: Actually, the _pointer_ to the string literal is on the stack - the string itself is an immutable blob of data in the execuable's static data section. Releasing the string will only release the NSString object; the string itself will still be sitting in memory.

Comment: @Nikita constant strings are in the executable itself. The only *stack*-allocated objects in Objective-C are un-copied blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.
No, as long the String isn't retained somewhere else the memory gets freed by the garbage collector sometime later. (Yes there is one, we just have more control when/if an object gets destroyed and the entire method isn't exactly by the book a garbage collector, but thats details.)

Yes due sometimes later. For a time, you use the memory of booth objects. :)